# Delphi - Enumerate the Disk(s) and other Drives on Windows PC

Tags: delphi, winapi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get drive information (free space, etc.) for drives on Windows and populate a memo box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644242/get-drive-information-free-space-etc-for-drives-on-windows-and-populate-a-mem)

I am quite new to programing (especially Delphi), and have been unable to find any examples as to how to enumerate all the drives on a PC.

I really care about Hard Disks and CD-Rom drives but I have been unable to find anything useable.

Can anyone point me in the direction of a good working sample?

Comment: I am really very sorry, I searched before I posted, but did not see the other post. Should I delete my question?

Comment: That's alright. It *is* not easy to search for duplicates. I think you can leave your question here (besides, I don't think you even *can* delete it since an answer has been posted). In addition, this way is will be easier to find this topic at SO in the future, because then there are two questions with slightly different wording.

Comment: You should not worry about deleting it, and on a very selfish note I am happy, as you accepted the answer, where as the original poster did not. C'est la vie.

Comment: @RRUZ can you reopen this please as the orginal has been deleted.

Comment: The question that was marked as "original" is now deleted so this question should be reopened.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The simplest way is actually to use `GetDiskFreeSpaceEx` from the `sysutils.pas` file.

There are 2 parts to this example. the 1st is the important part using `GetDiskFreeSpaceEX`.

```
function DriveSpace(DriveLetter : String; var FreeSpace, UsedSpace, TotalSpace : int64) : Boolean;
begin
  Result := SysUtils.GetDiskFreeSpaceEx(Pchar(DriveLetter), UsedSpace, TotalSpace, @FreeSpace);

  if UsedSpace > 0 then
    UsedSpace := TotalSpace - FreeSpace;

  if not Result then
  begin
    UsedSpace   := 0;
    TotalSpace  := 0;
    FreeSpace   := 0;
  end;
end;
```

If you are going to request drives that you already know the drive letter for such as C: then that is all you need.

Usage would be something like:

```
var
  FS,
  US,
  TS : Int64
begin
  DriveSpace('C:', FS, US, TS);
  //Do something with the 3 variables.
end;
```

Having said that if you want to find the drives as well you could use something like this:

```
procedure ListDrivesOfType(DriveType : Integer; var Drives : TStringList);
var
  DriveMap,
  dMask : DWORD;
  dRoot : String;
  I     : Integer;
begin
  dRoot     := 'A:\'; //' // work around highlighting
  DriveMap  := GetLogicalDrives;
  dMask     := 1;

  for I := 0 to 32 do
  begin
    if (dMask and DriveMap) <> 0 then
      if GetDriveType(PChar(dRoot)) = DriveType then
      begin
        Drives.Add(dRoot[1] + ':');
      end;

    dMask := dMask shl 1;
    Inc(dRoot[1]);
  end;
end;
```

Note the DriveType integer, should be one of the following:

```
DRIVE_UNKNOWN     = 0;
DRIVE_NO_ROOT_DIR = 1;
DRIVE_REMOVABLE   = 2;
DRIVE_FIXED       = 3;
DRIVE_REMOTE      = 4;
DRIVE_CDROM       = 5;
DRIVE_RAMDISK     = 6;
```

(I have taken these straight out of `windows.pas`)

---

Now finally to answer your question (and this is very rough) the following would add information into a memo (called memo1) for all `FIXED HARD DRIVES`:

```
Procedure TAform.SomeNameICantThinkOfNow;
const
  BytesPerMB = 1048576;
var
  MyDrives   : TStringlist;
  I : Integer;
  FreeSpace,
  UsedSpace,
  TotalSpace : int64;
begin
  MyDrives := TStringlist.Create;
  ListDrivesOfType(DRIVE_FIXED, MyDrives);

  Memo1.Lines.Clear;

  for I := 0 to MyDrives.Count - 1 do
  begin
    FreeSpace  := 0;
    UsedSpace  := 0;
    TotalSpace := 0;

    if DriveSpace(MyDrives.Strings[I], FreeSpace, UsedSpace, TotalSpace) then
    begin
      FreeSpace  := FreeSpace  div BytesPerMB;
      UsedSpace  := UsedSpace  div BytesPerMB;
      TotalSpace := TotalSpace div BytesPerMB;

      Memo1.Lines.Add('Drive: ' + MyDrives.Strings[I] + ' = Free Space :' + IntToStr(FreeSpace) +
                      ' Used Space: ' + IntToStr(UsedSpace) + ' Total Space: ' + IntToStr(TotalSpace));
    end;
  end;
end;
```

I did say it would be nasty! I have just run this up in the IDE and it works, I have done as MB but really you should convert to Double and choose your formatting if doing as MB to be more precise as the example I have create above will of course just round up.

Hope this is of some small assistance.

Comment: Thank you I will look at this now, I would give you an up vote but it appears I am too new to the site. Sorry

Answer (score 2):

See [GLibWMI Library](http://neftali.clubdelphi.com/?p=589); With It you can access information about system drives.

Comment: +1 for making me discover this lib