# How do I search if a specific file name exists on the root of every drive?

Tags: delphi

I want to know what to do so that my program can find a specific file on every drive. I would like the program to search only the root of the drive and block it from accessing the subfolders of the root so that the program will not do unnecessary access.

My actual goal is, when the filename which exists on the root of one of the drives matches what I specify in my code, it can execute my commands on that directory.

Comment: Did you see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5635573/delphi-enumerate-the-disks-and-other-drives-on-windows-pc?

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand That's really far from what I'm trying to attain. Thanks for the referral nonetheless! I got some new ideas in mind by looking at that, though I would still need some info about my question above.

Comment: I don't think it is far from it at all. If you want to search for a specific file on the root of every drive, surely the first step is to *enumerate* the drives? I mean, when you know how to enumerate the drives, it is trivial to do a simple `FileExists` on each drive?

Comment: Doesn't a trivial `for var x := 'A' to 'Z' do
    if FileExists(x + ':\test.txt') then
      ShowMessageFmt('The file exists on drive %s:.', [string(x)]);` do it for you?

Comment: I see, I understand now what your point is. I just looked at the code that enumerates the drives on that thread, now it is clear to me. Big thanks! Actually, I have no experience with Delphi at all and I only did Python in the past. Today, I would like to modify an open-source program written in Delphi. I am seeing the two programming languages' similarities somehow.