# Find path to pg_dump.exe

Tags: windows, delphi, path

I am currently working on a project in Delphi that uses Postgres as DataBase.

I am using pg_dump.exe to create a full backup.
But I need to know the exact path of pg_dump.exe on target machines.

it can be on C:\prgram files\ or C:\program files (x86) . also any Other partition (d:,e:,...)

Putting a copy of pg-dump.exe in my application folder does not solve the problem.

**UPDATE**

searching the file by its name on all drives is not a good solution.

in this case, I must calculate the checksum of file for all versions of PostgreSQL.also for PG_restore

(If there is no other way, finally I will do that)

because

1-Their may be some copy of this file in the wrong paths. ( PG_DUMP.exe in a folder without dlls and it won't run. I checked it )

2-a user file with the same name can fool the program( even a copy of  a worm or virus with the name of PG_DUMP.exe

3-People get backups on emergency situations. I think it is not so wise solution to search for a file in hundreds of thousands of files on user HDD

Comment: If pg_dump.exe is in the path, then you can use `where pg_dump.exe` to find out where it is.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1740561/62576 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/6546105/62576 This question doesn't show any research effort at all.

Comment: @KenWhite Thanks to your reply. I think this answer  is anot good solution .finding a file by its name is easy as pie.

do you suggest to me the worst way? if there is another file with the same name (even a virus) I will execute this file only its name is pg_dump.I am asking if there is any registry value or a tricky ay finding the real file I need

Comment: @nolaspeaker can't rely on this. It is not on the path with normal installation. I tested it.could not find the file for given patterns.

Comment: So find `pg_dump.exe` and then check for additional files that are in the same folder. If a malware author wants to use `pg_dump` to trick you into running their code, what makes you think they couldn't also tamper with registry information?

Comment: @KenWhite malware was just an example to say finding a file based on its name is not a good solution.but if there is not any other way...
.then there is only one solution. Search for this file and other needed files on the first run to find location. I was hoping for a better way. Thank you for your replay.

Answer (score 3):

you should change path of pg_dump.exe

as following
open pgadmin4 > file > preference> path  > pinary bath
and change path to bin

[image]